# WPF IsSelected animation, how to do it the correct way with event/data triggers in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, code-behind, wpf-animation

I have been able to do the above with the following code in my subclassed TabItem:

```
protected override void OnSelected(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelected(e);

        if (this.StoryBoard == null)
        {
            ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Transparent, Colors.AliceBlue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
            {
                AutoReverse = true,
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("Background.Color"));

            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Children.Add(anim);

            this.StoryBoard = sb;
        }

        VisualTree.FindParent<OMWTabControl>(this).Items.Cast<OMWTabItem>().ToList().ForEach(n =>
        {
            if (n.StoryBoard != null)
            {
                n.StoryBoard.Stop();
            }
        });

        this.StoryBoard.Begin();
    }
```

I know I am butchering the correct way to do this - I should be using DataTriggers I believe with Setters.

I have done extensive searching and it's all in XAML which is mostly intrepretable into C#, but not all.

Can someone point me to the "correct" way to do this in code behind?

Comment: For clarification:

I am trying to make a button's background color flash (change color) when it is selected, so I need to bind to the IsSelected dependency property

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to know about any methods, interfaces, classes, or just about anything about the .NET Framework, just go to MSDN. You could have gone to the [Storyboard.TargetProperty Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for a super quick answer to your question. From the linked page:

```
public StoryboardExample()
{
    // Create a name scope for the page.
    NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

    this.WindowTitle = "Animate Properties using Storyboards";
    StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    myStackPanel.MinWidth = 500;
    myStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(30);
    myStackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
    myTextBlock.Text = "Storyboard Animation Example";
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myTextBlock);

    // 
    // Create and animate the first button. 
    // 

    // Create a button.
    Button myWidthAnimatedButton = new Button();
    myWidthAnimatedButton.Height = 30;
    myWidthAnimatedButton.Width = 200;
    myWidthAnimatedButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    myWidthAnimatedButton.Content = "A Button";

    // Set the Name of the button so that it can be referred 
    // to in the storyboard that's created later. 
    // The ID doesn't have to match the variable name; 
    // it can be any unique identifier.
    myWidthAnimatedButton.Name = "myWidthAnimatedButton";

    // Register the name with the page to which the button belongs. 
    this.RegisterName(myWidthAnimatedButton.Name, myWidthAnimatedButton);

    // Create a DoubleAnimation to animate the width of the button.
    DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    myDoubleAnimation.From = 200;
    myDoubleAnimation.To = 300;
    myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));          

    // Configure the animation to target the button's Width property.
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, myWidthAnimatedButton.Name); 
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Button.WidthProperty));

    // Create a storyboard to contain the animation.
    Storyboard myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);

    // Animate the button width when it's clicked.
    myWidthAnimatedButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Begin(myWidthAnimatedButton);
        };


    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myWidthAnimatedButton);

    // 
    // Create and animate the second button. 
    // 

    // Create a second button.
    Button myColorAnimatedButton = new Button();
    myColorAnimatedButton.Height = 30;
    myColorAnimatedButton.Width = 200;
    myColorAnimatedButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    myColorAnimatedButton.Content = "Another Button";

    // Create a SolidColorBrush to paint the button's background.
    SolidColorBrush myBackgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    myBackgroundBrush.Color = Colors.Blue;

    // Because a Brush isn't a FrameworkElement, it doesn't 
    // have a Name property to set. Instead, you just 
    // register a name for the SolidColorBrush with 
    // the page where it's used. 
    this.RegisterName("myAnimatedBrush", myBackgroundBrush);

    // Use the brush to paint the background of the button.
    myColorAnimatedButton.Background = myBackgroundBrush;

    // Create a ColorAnimation to animate the button's background.
    ColorAnimation myColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
    myColorAnimation.From = Colors.Red;
    myColorAnimation.To = Colors.Blue;
    myColorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(7000));    

    // Configure the animation to target the brush's Color property.
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myColorAnimation, "myAnimatedBrush");                        
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myColorAnimation, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));    

    // Create a storyboard to contain the animation.
    Storyboard myColorAnimatedButtonStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    myColorAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Children.Add(myColorAnimation);

    // Animate the button background color when it's clicked.
    myColorAnimatedButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            myColorAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Begin(myColorAnimatedButton);
        };


    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myColorAnimatedButton);
    this.Content = myStackPanel;

}
```

Please visit the linked page for further information.

Comment: Forgive me if I missed it, but I don't see anywhere where it references with it is selected or not.  I know how to setup an animation based on the click event, I need something that will stop animating the other TabItems when another TabItem is selected.

Comment: Perhaps if you took a little while longer to clearly explain your requirements (using words) in your question, you'd get more accurate answers?